SCOTUS on Trump v. Anderson writes how Colorado determined that Trump is an insurrectionist, but did not change that, is he by law a insurrectionist?
See the first three pages of   https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/23pdf/23-719_19m2.pdf
where SCOTUS details what Colorado determined, but addresses only that they kept him off the ballot. So is Trump by law still an oath-breaking insurrectionist?
Would that Colorado determination that Trump is an oath-breaking insurrectionist have any influence in a Federal court in a case against him using 18 U.S.C. § 2383?
Can the Harris campaign accurately claim that Trump is a convicted oath-breaking insurrectionist, or must they use the word "adjudicated" rather than "convicted"?


So is Trump by law still an oath-breaking insurrectionist?

According to SCOTUS, no.

Would that Colorado determination that Trump is an oath-breaking insurrectionist have any influence in a Federal court in a case against him using 18 U.S.C. § 2383?

It may. The parties may refer to the analysis made by that court.

Can the Harris campaign accurately claim that Trump is a convicted oath-breaking insurrectionist, or must they use the word "adjudicated" rather than "convicted"?

No, he has not been convicted of that particular crime. He has been convicted of others. The Colorado courts only discussed whether he's falling under the scope of the 14th amendment restrictions on the eligibility to stand for election, nothing else.

To be clear, are these answeres just guesses? I don't see any explanation for you reached your conclusion that a court ruling retains the force of law after being reversed by the Supreme Court of the United States.

What was reversed was the instructions to the secretary of State, not the factual findings

@littleadv but factual findings only give rise to issue estoppel when the final order they support remains live.

Th efirst 3 pages of tehSCOTUS ruling,   https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/23pdf/23-719_19m2.pdf

I see what you're saying, corrected.

Jen: What does that mean, in a layman's language?

@BruceAtwood if the order was reversed then reasoning for the order doesn't matter

@littleady: Yes, it does not matter, moot for this purpose, but doesn't the judgement of the underlying fact still stand? SCOTUS said they did not address the facts. If a judge overrules a sentence, does't the guilty verdict stand, and only the sentence is revisited? What if Colorado does not allow insurrectists on its police forces? Would Trump be disqualified from that?

In this case there's no guilty verdict, there was no jury, there was no criminal conviction. What Colorado does in Colorado is up to Colorado, but for federal office the scotus says Colorado doesn't have a right to decide

@ bdb484; COLORADO S.C. ruled Trump took an oath, there was an insurrection, Trump took part in it, and he wants to be an officer of the US again. SCOTUS acknowledged that but explicitly did not address it.  (this got omitted from my earlier comment) It was a civil Judgement in CO so it is he judged by law to be an insurrectionist?

@littlady:  As I read SCOTUS, they just ruled that CO can't make a judgement to keep him of the US ballot. Isn't he still disqualified for state office?  i.e. an insurrectionist? That is, it wouldn't take a whole new trial he already has been ruled to be an insurrectionist for CO purposes?

@BruceAtwood he's not running for any state office, so the question you're asking is moot

@BruceAtwood if the supreme court can dispose of a case by overturning one part of a lower court's ruling, they typically ignore the rest of the ruling.  Their non-overturning of a certain line of reasoning isn't the same as upholding that line of reasoning.  Rather, it means that they haven't expressed an opinion on it.  Contrary to the (current) opening of this answer, they didn't rule that he isn't an insurrectionist, only that the CO court did not have the authority to exclude him from the federal ballot on the facts presented.

@BruceAtwood As to state office, if he ran for one, there would be a new court case in which the court would not be bound by the supreme court ruling because the different facts would make it inapplicable.  Whether lower Colorado courts would be bound by the earlier CO supreme court ruling, I do not know, but it seems likely that the case would end up before the CO supreme court on appeal, where they could overturn or reaffirm the earlier ruling ("likely" only if we overlook the high improbability of Trump running for state office in Colorado).

@phoog there seems to be a difference of interpretation between what Jen and bdb484 are saying and what you're saying. My understanding of their argument is that if the higher court reversed the decision of the lower court then the reasoning for that decision is no longer case law. This makes sense, especially since the CO discussion was only within the scope of 14th amendment eligibility, and if the CO courts had no authority to have that discussion then whatever determination they made is irrelevant.

The Colorado courts explicitly do have the authority to rule on 14th amendment eligibility with respect to state offices (p. 6, "We conclude that States may disqualify persons holding or attempting to hold state office"; emphasis in original). Jen is saying is that the factual determinations of the Colorado courts may be relitigated because the case was overturned, i.e., as you say, that it "is no longer case law," which means it's an open question. I don't think I said anything contrary to that, but rather that I didn't know.

@phoog right, that was not what was litigated so is not relevant to the question (which is moot, anyway)

That was not the question before them, and that is not what they addressed.
The question was did the State have the authority to remove someone from the ballot based on Section 3 of the 14th Amendment.
Their answer is basically that Congress has the power to remove someone based upon Section 3 of the 14th Amendment, and nobody else.
Whether someone committed insurrection, whether they have been convicted of insurrection (and in what court…traffic, state, federal or even the Supreme Court itself) are all irrelevant.  Based upon this ruling I would expect Congress could order someone removed from the ballot without a conviction in any court, just their own determination and whatever mechanism they developed.
Congress could presumably delegate this task to some group (within Congress or outside of Congress), but at the moment, if someone is to be proactively removed from the ballots, it is squarely their sole responsibility to develop such a mechanism.  It is probable that Federal Court’s have the power to decide if a case were to be brought before them, and so that would a mechanism that already exist, albeit not one that is proactive.
As for Colorado’s Supreme Court decision that they could remove someone from the ballot, they laid out their decision on 8 points/holdings, none of them reference or relied on a criminal conviction so “convicted oath-breaking insurrectionist” would be chancy at best, even if it hadn’t been overturned.

I think the point of this question is that SCOTUS never refuted the Colorado court's finding. So according to the CO Supreme Court, Trump is an insurrectionist.

"whether they have been convicted of insurrection (and in what court…traffic, state, federal or even the Supreme Court itself) are all irrelevant": this is incorrect.  If someone is convicted of having violated 18 USC 2383 then they are ineligible to hold federal office.  Because that inability is pursuant to an act of congress, it is consistent with the court's opinion in Trump v. Anderson.  Congress can't simply vote to ban someone from office as an insurrectionist because that would violate the constitutional guarantee of due process and the ban on bills of attainder.

@phoog: that’s not what TvA says.  It says that Congress has to create a mechanism to notify the States that someone is ineligible.  That could involve a court, but doesn’t have to*.  Given that it doesn’t impose any other penalty than ineligibility to hold office, a congressional investigation  followed by a resolution could be sufficient to determine who was ineligible.  *Doesn’t have to at the moment, the Supreme Court says that Congress has to come up with a mechanism, not that any such mechanism would be Constitutional.

@jmoreno which part of the opinion says that congress has to create such a mechanism?  The opinion certainly cites 18 USC 2383 explicitly as an example of Congress "giv[ing] effect to Section 3 with respect to would-be or existing federal office-holders."

@phoog: 18 USC 2383 isn’t an enforcement mechanism.  To be removed from the ballot because of it, removal would have to be ordered by a federal authority. After the 1870 Enforcement Act and until sometime in the mid 1940’s that would have been federal attorney’s (at least that’s my understanding).  18 USC 2383 could be applied by Congress post election (having been convicted would indeed make the individual ineligible, just as being 34 years old would)

@jmoreno if someone were running for office who had been convicted under 2383, there would be an order from a federal authority rendering them ineligible to run for federal office, namely the federal court that had convicted the (intending) candidate.  This would be sufficient for a state court to order removal from the ballot. Congress enforces the amendment "by appropriate legislation," including 2383 as noted in the opinion, which literally calls "a federal crime punishable by disqualification from holding office under the United States" a "procedure for enforcing disqualification."

@phoog: consider the recent election with 3 contra-factual changes. (1) Trump was convicted in a federal court for for violating 2383, (2) Colorado, Maine and Illinois were not challenged on their removing him from the ballot, (3) Congress then “removes that disability” (him being forbidden to hold office).  That has happened for lesser offices (except for the removal from the ballot).  The only difference would be that in 3 States, the people were deprived of their right to vote for the candidate of their choice by their State government. That is what this decision says cannot be.

“But States have no power under the Constitution to enforce Section 3 with respect to federal offices, especially the Presidency.”  Section 5 (enforcement) is at the discretion of Congress, and is not self executing.

@jmoreno if Congress were to remove the disability then of course the state would not be able to exclude the candidate from the ballot on the basis of the conviction. My point concerns a conviction without removal of disability. That section 5 is not self executing means that it may only be enforced pursuant to (federal) legislation, and as the opinion notes, section 2383 is an example of enforcing legislation. After someone is convicted under 2383 (unless the disability is removed or the conviction reversed) a state can exclude the person from a federal ballot without further federal action.
